# Sending requests to Elasticsearch with axios

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, axios

I'm working on a react app which needs to fetch data from elsaticsearch.
In frontend, actually I'm trying to use axios to do the request:

```
const query = {
  query: {
    match: {
      "_id": "AV12n5KzsohD5gXzTnOr"
    }
  }
};

axios.get('http://localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/_search', query)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

I want to get the specific document with some ID. The above query actually works inside kibana. However, the above query returns all the documents inside my-type, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry I updated the post, thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the below should work. Although the [Axios README](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) says that `data` is specifically only for `PUT`, `POST`, and `PATCH` requests, I didn't see anything in the code that enforces this, and a simplified test shows that the request body is indeed sent for `GET` requests:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/_search', {
  data: JSON.stringify(query),
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

**EDIT**

Note that I've only tested this in Node.js, not in a browser. Browsers may be less inclined to include request bodies with `GET` requests.

**EDIT 2**

Elasticsearch seems to allow [sending the request body in a parameter instead](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string), perhaps because of this very issue.

This should do the trick:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/_search', {
  params: {
    source: JSON.stringify(query),
    source_content_type: 'application/json'
  }
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

**EDIT 3**

This does indeed seem to be a general restriction on making `GET` requests in browsers. Per [the documentation for XMLHttpRequest.send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send):

> If the request method is GET or HEAD, the argument is ignored and request body is set to null.

Comment: Thanks! I tried exactly in your way but still, I got all the documents instead of the one I want. I think my get-request doesn't send any payload to elasticsearch, weird...

Comment: Hi smarx, your second edit actuall worked! Hmmm.. I guess axios is the kind of library which doesn't accept a request body for non-POST requests. Anyway, thanks for your help:)

Comment: I suspect that Axios handles it fine (as it worked in Node.js), but browsers do not.

Comment: To my knowledge, axios seems work very differently in browser/node. In browser, it has to use XMLHttprequest as http adapter. See this: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/456

Comment: Yes, and I suspect it's the browser restrictions (i.e. XHR) that prevent the request body from being sent.

Comment: Agree I think that's the reason.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `.post()`

From the Elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html)

> Both HTTP GET and HTTP POST can be used to execute search with body. Since not all clients support GET with body, POST is allowed as well

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/_search?q=${_id:AV12n5KzsohD5gXzTnOr}`)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. But for more complicated DSL query, I think smarx's second edit should be the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for others if they come here. Following way worked for me: (Don't pay attention to sample data)

```
axios({
    url: 'your ES url',
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: 0,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      query: {
        bool: {
          filter: [
            { match_all: {} },
            { match_phrase: { 'data.gateway': { query: 'gateway1' } } },
            { match_phrase: { 'data.sensor': { query: '10001' } } },
            { range: { 'data.dateTime': { lte: '2020-05-26 20:25:00' } } },
            {
              range: {
                receivedInES: {
                  format: 'strict_date_optional_time',
                  gte: '2020-05-25T19:37:23.621Z',
                  lte: '2020-05-26T19:37:23.621Z'
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
  })
```