# Elasticsearch query for getting all nodes of a graph's adjacency list (building graph in javascript)

Tags: elasticsearch

Have a set of ES documents in an index each like

```
{
    currId: '<some id>',
    prevId: '<some id>',
    parents: ['NULL']
}
```

where (for the sake of simplifying this example problem) `prevId` is used when there is only one parent, else use `parents` (in reality there are other reasons why it is design like this).

So a set of documents like

```
{currId: '0', prevId: 'NULL', parents: ['NULL']}
{currId: '1', prevId: '0', parents: ['NULL']},
{currId: '2', prevId: '0', parents: ['NULL']},
{currId: '3', prevId: 'NULL', parents: ['1', '2']},
{currId: '4', prevId: 'NULL', parents: ['1', '2']}
```

imply a graph

```
   |-- 1 -- |__3
0--         |__
   |-- 2 -- |  4
```

(sorry if the ascii art is not great (in words: 0 is parent of 1 and 2, which are both parents of both 3 and 4)). Basically, each node has two fields that, combined, contain the full list of that node's parents. **Note that there may be other documents in the index that are not connected to this graph shown here that I would want to ignore in the query**.

Very new to ES, so very hard to think of even where to start to think about this problem. Is there a way that I can query to get all documents that make up a connected component graph using only knowledge of a **single, random** document that is in that component (not necessarily the graph rooted at zero in the example above) (eg. given only info of a single randomly selected node, obtain all of the other connected nodes)?

** Note, this is being done in a JavaScript REST API request to an ES server via axios (https://github.com/axios/axios), so things like for-loops and such could conceivably be used (but am trying to avoid that if possible and just use a single query (though I admittedly don't really know what the performance trade-offs would be here)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since am more used to JavaScript than the elasticsearch query language, I ended up just using a DFS implementation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) with simple ES queries to get all of the nodes connected to a single selected node `this.selectedNode` one DFS run to get all the parents (and other ancestors) and another DFS run to get all the children. The code is presented below (its a bit verbose, but main functions to note are `buildGraph` and `_dfs` to get the gist of the algorithm here (also note, using a field *sources* instead of *parents* as in the question)):

```js
async function _getParents(child) {//see https://tutorialzine.com/2017/07/javascript-async-await-explained
    // queries our main DB of nodes to get all nodes n with... 
    // n.currId = child.prevId or child.sources.includes(n.currId)
    let data = {
        "sort": {"timestamp": {"order": "desc"}},
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {"match": {"currId": child.prevId}},
                    //{"match": {"currId": child.sources}}
                ],
                "should": child.sources.map((id) => {return {"match": {"currId": id}}})
            }//TODO: use pure ES query to match against ES sources array
        }
    }

    let nodes = []
    let res = await axios.get("http://myesserver:9200/myindex/mytype/_search", {
            // for submiting to elasticsearch, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45292081/8236733
            params: {
                source: JSON.stringify(data),
                source_content_type: 'application/json'
            }
        })

    console.log('NEW PARENT NODES')
    nodes = res['data']['hits']['hits'].map(record => {return record['_source']} )
    console.log(nodes)
    return nodes
}
async function _getChildren(parent) {// see https://tutorialzine.com/2017/07/javascript-async-await-explained
    // queries our main DB of nodes to get all nodes n with... 
    // n.prevId == parent.currId or n.sources.includes(parent.currId) 
    let data = {
        "sort": {"timestamp": {"order": "desc"}},
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {"match": {"prevId": parent.currId}},
                    {"match": {"sources": parent.currId}}
                ]
            }
        }
    }

    let nodes = []
    let res = await axios.get("http://myesserver:9200/myindex/mytype/_search", {
            // for submiting to elasticsearch, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45292081/8236733
            params: {
                source: JSON.stringify(data),
                source_content_type: 'application/json'
            }
        })

    console.log('NEW CHILD NODES')
    nodes = res['data']['hits']['hits'].map(record => {return record['_source']} )
    console.log(nodes)
    return nodes
}
/**
 *
 *
 * @param {*} root
 * @param {(v)=>{}} stopper callback for conditional to determine whether to visit a node
 * @param {(v)=>{}} visit callback for what to do when visit each node
 * @param {(v)=>{}} getNext callback for how to get the children of a node
 */
async function _dfs(root, stopper, visit, getNext) {//see https://tutorialzine.com/2017/07/javascript-async-await-explained
    /* getting children */
    /* using DFS method */
    console.log('starting wth root node:')
    console.log(root)
    let s = []
    s.push(root)
    console.log('initialized stack (FIXME: not showing correctly for some reason):')
    console.log(s)
    while (s.length > 0) {
        let v = s.pop()
        console.log('popped:')
        console.log(v)
        console.log(v.sources)
        if (stopper(v)) {
            /* save this node for the graph */
            visit(v)                          
            /* get the children of this node */
            let kids = await getNext(v)                     
            s = s.concat(kids)
            console.log('concated stack:')
            console.log(s)
        }
    }
}
/**
 *
 *
 * @param {*} startn the node of the graph that we initially start with
 * @param {*} nodes
 * @param {*} edges
 */
async function buildGraph(startn, nodes, edges) {
    // Had to do async all the way down b/c of the async axios requests to the ES server
    //see https://tutorialzine.com/2017/07/javascript-async-await-explained

    /* getting ancestors */
    // if wanted to get siblings as well, this would be the DFS branch to implement that in
    let discovered = []
    await _dfs(startn, 
        (v)=>{return !discovered.includes(v.currId)}, 
        (v)=>{
            discovered.push(v.currId)
            nodes.push({id: v.currId, label: v.currLocation})
            if (v.prevId != 'NULL') {
                edges.push({from: v.prevId, to: v.currId})
            } 
            if (v.sources.length > 0 && v.sources[0] != 'NULL') {
                for (let i=0; i < v.sources.length; i++) {
                    edges.push({from: v.sources[i], to: v.currId})
                }
            }
        }, 
        (v)=>{return _getParents(v)})

    console.log('completed collecting ancestor nodes')
    console.log(nodes)

    /* getting children */
    // remove root from discovered, so can do another dfs
    for (var i=discovered.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (discovered[i] === startn.currId) {
            discovered.splice(i, 1);
            // break;       //<-- Uncomment  if only the first term has to be removed
        }
    }
    await _dfs(startn, 
        (v)=>{return !discovered.includes(v.currId)}, 
        (v)=>{
            discovered.push(v.currId)
            // can't add origin node with same id to graph again in react-graph-vis
            if (v.currId != startn.currId) {
                nodes.push({id: v.currId, label: v.currLocation})
            }
            if (v.prevId != 'NULL') {
                edges.push({from: v.prevId, to: v.currId})
            } 
            if (v.sources.length > 0 && v.sources[0] != 'NULL') {
                for (let i=0; i < v.sources.length; i++) {
                    edges.push({from: v.sources[i], to: v.currId})
                }
            }
        }, 
        (v)=>{return _getChildren(v)})

    console.log('completed collecting child nodes')
    console.log(nodes)
}

let nodes = []
let edges = []
buildGraph(this.selectedNode, nodes, edges).then(res => {
    console.log('buildGraph promise result:')
    console.log(res, nodes, edges)
    this.setState({nodes: nodes, edges: edges})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the first degree connections, a boolean query with a should clause is sufficient. For example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                    {"term": {"prevId":0}},
                    {"term": {"parents":0}}
                ]
        }
    }
}
```